# Having issues calling an ID after I have appended data from an ajax call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Ok,

So I have a .on click event which is called to an ajaxed script. The script returns a set of HTML information.

Now, what I seem to be having an issue with and maybe I am just not typing the right search terms in for this so my apologies if this was answered already.

When the html is appended to the correct box, the user is then able to click a link on that box, drop down the box and see a new input box. The user should be able to type the text in and hit the enter key and it should work.

When I run an inspect element, I do see the element's ID properly inserted, but it is like javascript doesn't even recognize the new element id.

UPDATE: I am really not sure why you need code to be able to answer this question, however here it is. The code works normally unless the above happens so yes I am appending it, and yes I am SURE i am appending it, please make sure to read everything before posting a comment, thanks!

```
 $('body').on('keypress', '.peapComment', function(event) {         
            if(event.which == 13) {
                var peap_id = $(this).attr('rel');
                var comment = $(this).val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "index.php",
                    data: {
                        page: "postPeapComment",
                        peap_id: peap_id,
                        comment: comment,
                    }
                }).done(function(msg) {
                    console.log(msg);
                    $('#comment_' + peap_id).append(msg);


                });
                console.log('Send to Peap #' + peap_id + ': ' + comment);
                $('#commentbox_' + peap_id).val('');
            }
        });
```

Comment: Please show the relevant HTML and jQuery or it is very hard to help find the problem :)

Comment: My guess is that you need to [delegate your event handler](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events).

Comment: Updated the question with code.

Comment: where is your on click function? im pretty sure this is an issue of event delegation but u gotta provide ur on click event so I know that for sure :)

Comment: there is no need for an on click function, nothing is being clicked... The user enters text, hits enter, an ajax call is fired off to the server with the data. This works if I refresh the page, the comments work fine. This not working if a new "peap" is added to the page though, even though all of the HTML elements are the same with the unique id's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have tested your code, and it seems to work without problems for me. My assumption would be that the data returned from your ajax call, is failing to return the proper "Peap_ID" or not returning anything all around, as this is the only way I can reproduce what you have claimed your error is, otherwise the code you have posted looks great.

Comment: Aw, so I double checked this and realized my rel was being returned as empty. Once I added the data for rel event it worked as I expected it should. Thank you for testing this out instead of just down playing my issue. This is what I expect from a community like this!

Comment: No problem, let me know if you have any further questions.